# how to use a matrix to extract values from a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, extract

suppose I have a data frame which 2 columns of it is A and B. A and B can take values between 1 to 150. and I have a 150 * 150 matrix. I want a new column which is an element of the matrix in row A and column B.

Example : suppose matrix is 2*2 instead of 150* 150

dataframe D:

```
    A        B
    1        2
    2        1
```

Matrix M:

```
       13      12
       2        4
```

new column:

```
        C
        12
        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We  can use the `data.frame` as `matrix` and use that for subsetting.  Here, the "D" once converted to `matrix` acts as row/column index to return the elements from 'M'

```
D$C <- M[as.matrix(D)]
D
#  A B  C
#1 1 2 12
#2 2 1  2
```

#### data

```
D <- structure(list(A = 1:2, B = 2:1), class = "data.frame", 
     row.names = c(NA, -2L))
M <- cbind(c(13, 2), c(12, 4))
```

Comment: How it knows what is A and B?

Comment: @hghg It is based on indexing.  In the first column 'A', I guess it is the row index and in 'B', it is column index

Comment: @hghg  Here, I  am converting the whole dataset 'D', which contains only  2 columns 'A', and 'B'

Comment: @hghg If you have a data.frame with more number of columns, subset the columns i.e. `M[as.matrix(D[c("A", "B")])]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code with transpose `t()`

```
D$C <- M[t(t(D))]
```

or

```
D$C <- M[cbind(D$A, D$B)]
```

such that

```
> D
  A B  C
1 1 2 12
2 2 1  2
```

Comment: If you are thinking about making it different any way, use `M[cbind(D$A, D$B)]`

Comment: @akrun yes, added it

Comment: @hghg which method did you use?